Notify flutter app of finished express long running background task
I am using flutter and node express to create a skin disease diagnosis app and given the fact that I have a python worker that processes the image in the background,this task finishes after 10 seconds or so. I already have an endpoint in my express server that tells me if the processing is finished but after that I don't know how to notify the flutter app so I can update the frontend with the latest data. I only need suggestions, tools, packages that I can look into(directions). P.S: I don't use firebase
I tried chatting with gpt and he gave me some socket solution but I don't really like it, I thought maybe there is something cleaner I can work with.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
